# How to get if a player presses the TAB key in a forum

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I'm making a school project (a game of some sorts), and we all get a mail address from school. Now I record the mail address in a database and want to add a little feature. If the 'player' presses the tab key in the third forum box, the fourth gets automatically filled with the number they entered in the third box (student number) with @... after it.

How can I fire an event when the tab key is pressed in the third box? I now have:

```
<script>
      function autoMail() {
        if (event.keyCode == 9) {
          console.log("Mail is automatisch ingevuld!");
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      }
</script>

<td style="color: white; font-weight: bold;" onkeypress="autoMail()">Leerlingnummer:</td>
```

This doesn't work, however. So anyone has an Idea?

(BTW: I already have the onkeypress event somewhere else in the site, wich does work. But I can't figure out why this one doesn't...)

Comment: can we see the rest of the html and js?  Do you have a fiddle or codepen we can take a look at?

Comment: Maybe not an anwser, but just a good practice:
keyCode is not widely supported, use .which instead because it is supported by more browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to pass the event to function like this

```
 <td style="color: white; font-weight: bold;" onkeypress="autoMail(event)">Leerlingnummer:</td>
```

then you can use a variable to take the key, i put an alert to know the key number and for me tab is keynumber 0 so try it like the following code

```
function autoMail(e) {
        key = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;            
        if (key == 0) {
           alert("Mail is automatisch ingevuld!");  
           // code....           
        }
    }
```

if isn't the keynumber 0, you can add an alert with variable "key"